# I'm dockerizing my website setup. What is the best approach to send mails by PHP-FPM in a container?

Tags: php, postfix, docker, wordpress, sendmail

So i've seen [a](https://serverfault.com/questions/658367/how-to-get-php-fpm-to-log-to-stdout-stderr-when-running-in-a-docker-container) [couple](https://serverfault.com/questions/658367/how-to-get-php-fpm-to-log-to-stdout-stderr-when-running-in-a-docker-container) [of](https://serverfault.com/questions/788672/sending-mail-from-inside-docker-container) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798538/use-php-sendmail-from-docker-container-to-send-through-host-postfix) about setting up notifications for PHP-based websites, so i'd like to ask you for the best approach. For that,

I have:

- a WordPress website with custom PHP packages hosted locally, no containers,
- working sendmail setup being used by PHP working as a smart host, we use a Mailgun account and send mails generated by WordPress to their SMTP,

I want:

- the same WordPress website I host locally but in Docker,
- emails are being sent in the same way as it was locally set,
- I want to avoid hosting anything outside Docker (except nginx).

Options I've seen are:

- hosting postfix locally (as it can listen on public port and docker0) and using SMTP client on the website container sending mails to a local postfix instance, then postfix instance sending emails to Mailgun SMTP,
- the same option as above but with hosting postfix on Docker,
- using just a small client on the website container and that's all what's needed (although no idea if that would work since I have no good experience in setting up mail servers).

Extra questions which would let me understand the problem better:

- since I want to avoid hosting anything locally, the best approach would be if I hosted Postfix on Docker container, then some small SMTP client like `msmtp` on the website container so I can replace `sendmail` being used as a default way to send mails. Do I have to expose port 25 outside the Docker network or having the port exposed within the network is enough?
- can I just use a small SMTP client like `msmtp` on the website container and that would be enough? if not, why?